# Byethost web service won’t work. It won’t connect with the ftp server on port21

Tags: html, css, web-services, webserver

I tried to login to cpanel today and it’ll not let me. It won’t sync with a dreamweaver as well. Everything was working fine yesterday. I tried without antivirus and on other devices today. It says,”unable to connect to ftp server on port 21.”

Answer (score 1):

It started working today. Looks like that was the servers fault. The servers didn’t support the port21 and ftp methods of connecting which is the only one that’s correct.